# Scraping Youtube Data from Cheerio

Tags: javascript, react-native, cheerio

[image]

I am scraping Youtube data from cheerio library in react native, and I am finding it a bit difficult.
I want to traverse the node that is selected, that is, div having id = "items" and iterate that node to get the values. But the problem, I am getting is, every time I run this code snippet:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
console.warn($('.style-scope', '.ytd-grid-renderer').html());
```

I am getting null value in console. Anything I should do  to fix it? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: check the body html. May be you are being blocked by `recaptcha`

Comment: I am getting the html.

Comment: Why not work with Youtube API directly?

Comment: They have limited number of calls. I can't pay them as I am from country that doesnt have paying system available and also I cannot afford it.

Comment: I have to store that in Firebase, but you know, to have the data saved from firebase, I require non-free account type in Firebase too. It is awful situation for usu here. Also, I can't simply save the data once in every user account because the data might change in time. So , only option left to me was scrapping the data

Answer (score 1):

`.html` works on one selector.

Ideally your selector should be `$('.style-scope.ytd-grid-renderer')`

Since you want to target the element that has both classes on same element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get video data from YouTube with Cheerio, because YouTube dynamically loads content on the page via JavaScript. To get what you want, you need to use some browser automation, e.g. [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/). In the code below I show you how you can do this (also check [it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-YouTube-search-results-with-NodeJS-SerpApi#withPuppeteer.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const searchString = "star wars";                                // what we want to search

const requestParams = {
  baseURL: `https://www.youtube.com`,
  encodedQuery: encodeURI(searchString),                        // what we want to search for in URI encoding
};

async function scrollPage(page, scrollElements) {
  let currentElement = 0;
  while (true) {
    let elementsLength = await page.evaluate((scrollElements) => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements).length;
    }, scrollElements);
    for (; currentElement < elementsLength; currentElement++) {
      await page.waitForTimeout(200);
      await page.evaluate(
        (currentElement, scrollElements) => {
          document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements)[currentElement].scrollIntoView();
        },
        currentElement,
        scrollElements
      );
    }
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    let newElementsLength = await page.evaluate((scrollElements) => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements).length;
    }, scrollElements);
    if (newElementsLength === elementsLength) break;
  }
}

async function fillDataFromPage(page) {
  const dataFromPage = await page.evaluate((requestParams) => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#contents > ytd-video-renderer")).map((el) => ({
      title: el.querySelector("a#video-title")?.textContent.trim(),
      link: `${requestParams.baseURL}${el.querySelector("a#thumbnail")?.getAttribute("href")}`,
      channel: {
        name: el.querySelector("#channel-info #channel-name a")?.textContent.trim(),
        link: `${requestParams.baseURL}${el.querySelector("#channel-info > a")?.getAttribute("href")}`,
        thumbnail: el.querySelector("#channel-info > a #img")?.getAttribute("src"),
      },
      publishedDate: el.querySelectorAll("#metadata-line > span")[1]?.textContent.trim(),
      views: el.querySelectorAll("#metadata-line > span")[0]?.textContent.trim(),
      length: el.querySelector("span.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer")?.textContent.trim(),
      description: el.querySelector(".metadata-snippet-container > yt-formatted-string")?.textContent.trim(),
      extensions: Array.from(el.querySelectorAll("#badges .badge")).map((el) => el.querySelector("span")?.textContent.trim()),
      thumbnail: el.querySelector("a#thumbnail #img")?.getAttribute("src"),
    }));
  }, requestParams);
  return dataFromPage;
}

async function getYoutubeOrganicResults() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const URL = `${requestParams.baseURL}/results?search_query=${requestParams.encodedQuery}`;

  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(URL);

  await page.waitForSelector("#contents > ytd-video-renderer");

  const scrollElements = "#contents > ytd-video-renderer";

  await scrollPage(page, scrollElements);

  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);

  const organicResults = await fillDataFromPage(page);

  await browser.close();

  return organicResults;
}

getYoutubeOrganicResults().then(console.log);
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Star Wars Battlefront 2 - Funny Moments Order #66",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LquShRk_3sw",
    "channel": {
      "name": "Jongo Phett",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/c/JongoPhett",
      "thumbnail": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLR-k_Ubr0aJgzNu91jAQCc-vnCOpyIkASWxIbm7rQ=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
    },
    "publishedDate": "16 hours ago",
    "views": "12K views",
    "length": "10:39",
    "description": "episode 66 of Star Wars Battlefront 2 Funny Moments, a montage of the funniest star wars clips in battlefront II. edited together by ...",
    "extensions": ["New"],
    "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LquShRk_3sw/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOgCEMoBSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLAFNjI-rEeq5mmDL6I4nXgxZyId3Q"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Most Powerful Character In All of Star Wars",
    "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTTv8mmxoTE",
    "channel": {
      "name": "The Stupendous Wave",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/c/TheStupendousWave",
      "thumbnail": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQ0T0u6VqryQ-Z5efb1qVTcUHthiH8EamJMKDAE=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
    },
    "publishedDate": "10 hours ago",
    "views": "29K views",
    "length": "12:22",
    "description": "For all sponsorship and business inquiries please contact: thestupendousscrub@gmail.com Business: ...",
    "extensions": ["New"],
    "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JTTv8mmxoTE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBdHe_wWjGruLfxz1acr-3jP0YltA"
  }
  ...and other results
]
```

You can read more about scraping YouTube from my blog posts [Web scraping YouTube search video results with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-search-video-results-with-nodejs/) and [Web scraping YouTube secondary search results with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-secondary-search-results-with-nodejs/).